# Blank Dialog on MessageBox on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, messagebox, windows-mobile-6.5

I use MessageBox in some moments of my application or ask something to alert the user, but in some situations the MessageBox appears on the screen without the dialog box, showing only the buttons and deterinados cases only shows the message text. The problem is intermittent and occurs only in devices with Windows Mobile 6.5. Does anyone know if there is any way around this problem, or at least the source of the problem?

Sample images below error.

MessageBox normal:
[Normal http://inovaservice2.cloudapp.net/Imagens/Screen01.jpg](http://inovaservice2.cloudapp.net/Imagens/Screen01.jpg)

MessageBox with error:
[Error http://inovaservice2.cloudapp.net/Imagens/Screen02.jpg](http://inovaservice2.cloudapp.net/Imagens/Screen02.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like a low memory situation.

Comment: I tried adding the lines GC.Collect and Application.DoEvents and apparently is working, already opened some 200 MessageBox and dont appear the error. Thank you!!